# Regex find a digit

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, `Hello, season 2 (VSF)` and I need to parse "2" out of it. Here is what I'm trying:

```
s = 'Hello, season 2 (VSF)'
re.findall('Season|Saison|Staffel[\s]+\d',s)
>>> ["Season"]
```

How would I get "Season 2" here?

Answer (score 1):

`Season|Saison|Staffel` should be grouped. Also specify [`re.IGNORECASE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) or `re.I` flag to match case-insensitively.

```
s = 'Hello, season 2 (VSF)'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:Season|Saison|Staffel)\s+\d+', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['season 2']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:Season|Saison|Staffel)\s+\d+', s) # without re.I
[]
```

Use non-capturing group. Otherwise the pattern include a capturing group and [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) return a list of matched group instead of match string.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(Season|Saison|Staffel)\s+\d+', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['season']
```